# Referencing LED Visibility using CAPL program?

Tags: capl, canoe

I'm trying to write some CAPL code to be able to hide an LED when a user presses on a button in my CANoe panel.  How can I call on the LED control name and change "Is visible at Runtime" to false?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to help you, please share some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (show us some of your code) and maybe a screenshot of the panel for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

For CAPL, there is a function `void enableControl(char panel[], char control[], long enable);`.

For C# there is a COM Property `Visible`.

Please check Vector Help Guide for references on how to use them.